# Twig / Symfony : I can't access variables of my relation

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am developing a website with Symfony 5.2 and I struggle with a basic thing.
I have an Entity called Project and an other one Client. They have a ManyToOne relationships together.

Project.php

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Client::class, inversedBy="projects", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $owner;
```

Client.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Project::class, mappedBy="owner", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $projects;
```

And I have a Twig which do a loop on projects. I have no issue retrieving my var from the Project Entity. But for a reason I ignore, I don't have access to my $owner var (Client Entity). My dump (inside the loop) of a project and of project.owner looks like ok https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNkCl.png :

```
            {{ dump(project) }}
            {{ dump(project.owner) }}
```

But if I wrote this, my owner is said to be null :

```
{{ dump(project.owner.lastName) }}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJxk9.png

I tried a lot of different things( like set the value {% set blabla = project.getOwner() %}, none of these works ) but I don't get why project.owner is set to null when I want to retrieve lastName when project.owner alone has values ok.

Thanks for reading guys, don't hesitate if you need further details to answer.

Have a good day,

Comment: 1) Is every project has a client? The field owner can be nullable and you are trying to get it in a loop. 2) Do you have a public method in Project entity to get an owner?

Comment: Ahah I feel stupid now. Indeed there was one project without client (do it before develop the client entity). Thanks for your time.